# Compiling error in Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, program-entry-point, undefined-symbol

I am trying to compile a file in Mac OS X but keep on getting the error

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could any one help to find out what this error means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `main` definition in the program which is the starting point of any executable. So, linker is complaining because it didn't find the entry point ( which is `main` ) for the final executable.

```
Undefined symbols:
"_main",
```

Meaning there is no `_main` in any of the source files compiled. ( i.e., `int main(void)`, `int main( int agrc, const char* argv[]` in C, C++ )

```
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

Meaning it is a linker error. Linker binds all the object files to a single executable. At this time it checks whether there is entry point at all for the executable. It isn't in your case, so it is complaining.

Comment: Also could you advise me how to add the glut library to my mac OSX so that i could compile glut programs directly from the terminal instead of using Xcode??

Comment: Check this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851557/why-wont-this-glut-program-compile-am-i-missing-libraries-or-headers

Comment: Well I want to compile it from the terminal in a MAC OSX itself not on a linux machine..the thread that you have mentioned talks of running it on a linux machine...??

Comment: Since you said you need build & run the program using terminal, that would definitely work. Try it once :)

Comment: i got the answer ...what i was missing was the command for running it in the terminal

Comment: gcc -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa robot.c -o robot this command would help in compiling the file..

Comment: noddy - Correct. That's how I did it on my Mac a year back. Sorry for the confusion caused :( But we can link it our selves but that is rather pointless when we have a straight forward way of doing on a Mac machine.